# How can I upload a whole folder to a server in android

Tags: android, upload, ftp, android-service, httprequest

I have a folder on the android device that I wish to upload to my server.

Using PHP on the server side.

it can be FTP or any other option..

(Oh, and I have to do it inside a service)..

Answer (score 0):

```
USE THIS :

public void goforIt(){


    FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect("192.168.2.57"); //Your server IP

        if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk")) //Your Login Creadentials
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";    

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.storeFile("/vivekm4a.m4a", in);
            in.close();
            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: But its a folder.. in this code you're uploading a file.. `/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a`..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you're right.

Okay for the folder try this then:

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent();
> intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
> // FTP URL (Starts with ftp://, sftp:// or ftps:// followed by hostname and port).
> Uri ftpUri = Uri.parse("ftp://yourftpserver.com");
> intent.setDataAndType(ftpUri, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andftp.uri");
> // FTP credentials (optional)
> intent.putExtra("ftp_username", "anonymous");
> intent.putExtra("ftp_password", "something@somewhere.com");
> //intent.putExtra("ftp_keyfile", "/sdcard/dsakey.txt");
> //intent.putExtra("ftp_keypass", "optionalkeypassword");
> // FTP settings (optional)
> intent.putExtra("ftp_pasv", "true");
> //intent.putExtra("ftp_resume", "true");
> //intent.putExtra("ftp_encoding", "UTF8");
> // Upload
> intent.putExtra("command_type", "upload");
> // Activity title
> intent.putExtra("progress_title", "Uploading folder ...");
> intent.putExtra("local_file1", "/sdcard/localfolder");
> // Optional initial remote folder (it must exist before upload)
> intent.putExtra("remote_folder", "remotefolder/uploadedfolder");
> startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
> ```

Comment: well.. how can I do it with an intent? (I have to do it inside a service)